# Debugging ERROR 000664 when changing field name with arcpy.AlterField_management()?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I am trying to change a field name in featureclasses (shapefiles) using AlterField_management, however I receive the following error message:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 14, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3332, in
>   AlterField     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000664: Invalid input: The
>   type of dataset is not supported.

The code:

```
import arcpy

from os import path

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True  

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\johnny\trial' 

    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(): 

    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)

    for field in fieldList:

        #if field.baseName != "NEAR_DIST":

        arcpy.AlterField_management(fc, 'NEAR_DIST', 'distance', "distance", "DOUBLE")
```

Answer (score 5):

In the [Help for arcpy.AlterField_management()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/alter-field-properties.htm) it says with my bolding:

> This tool provides the ability to rename fields or rename field
>   aliases for any **geodatabase table or feature class**.

From your code the workspace that you have set, which is a folder, rather than a geodatabase, makes me think that you are trying to use this on shapefiles instead of feature classes.

Comment: yes, you are right, I was trying to use it with shapefiles rather than on feature classes. In this case, any thoughts?

Comment: Renaming fields in shapefiles has been covered in earlier Q&A here.  If you do not find that already answered then you should ask a new question (but research first).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an indentation problem - is the example formatted correctly?

The last few lines should be

```
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(): 

        fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)

        for field in fieldList:

            #if field.baseName != "NEAR_DIST":

            arcpy.AlterField_management(fc, 'NEAR_DIST', 'distance', "distance", "DOUBLE")
```

If fc has gone out of scope, it will be passed into AlterField_management as None and would generate an invalid input error.

Comment: it was not formatted correctly. in the arcpy code block it was as you typed.